# Listing data of multiple content type

Tags: drupal, graphql, gatsby

Am trying to create a listing page and sort it with respect to date for all the type of product available on my site (simple, clothing)

If I use the following query

```
{

  allCommerceProductTypeCommerceProductType{
    nodes{
      relationships{
        commerce_product__clothing{
          title
        }
        commerce_product__simple{
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it will return all the content but it will be under different keys and will not able to achieve the sorting

Expected output would be all the products getting listed under the same key

Comment: Where is the date field that you want to sort by?

Comment: at the same level as title